# ‘Times bigger’ meaning?

Tags: launch

When someone says “this star is 10,000 times bigger than the sun”, does that mean 10,000 suns can fit in it or it’s diameter is 10,000 bigger than the sun?

Comment: The statement is ambiguous without context. You should ask that *someone* what he/she means.

Comment: @JanDoggen I had the same thought, but to be fair to the OP, the phrasing is often used in the media without context and as Pearson answered, volume is almost exclusively meant.

Comment: when it say bigger it mens mass,and if it is larger it is area.this is my definition other people have an other definition of this.

Answer (score 3):

Volume is usually what is being referred to. So if you had a 1 m ball, and doubled the dimensions of it, it would be able to fit 8 balls in it (Of course, they would have to be cut in to pieces to fit).

Of course, it depends on the context in many cases. Volume is typically used because it gives the highest number, and thus seems the most impressive. The only other dimension that makes sense is diameter, but usually that is called out specifically if noted. Mass could also be used in some context, and while size and mass are not the same thing, some times we don't actually know the actual size of an object, only the mass, and thus mass might be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought that times bigger meant like radius or whatever. Thanks heaps.

Comment: Since there's no example or citation, and the question is "when someone says..." I think it's not appropriate to post an answer. This is just speculation. I could post an answer with the exact opposite conclusion and there would be no way to judge or objectively decide which is the right one. And that's a good test for an "opinion-based close vote". Corresponding Jupiter volume image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JexqX.jpg

Comment: @Caleb it could *definitely* mean radius or diameter, or even projected area. It really depends completely on the context. Until you add some context to your question, there is no "right" answer to this question.